# How to adjust image size in stack post?

Tags: support, feature-request, formatting, size-of-preview

If a good-quality image uploaded, it fully expands throughout screen, and interferes reading. Where-as , if I upload a highly compressed version of the image, to fit the size, the necessary details lost.

So, is there any option to adjust the image size? (like a click-and-drag) then the conontinuity in reading will-not be hampered, so, making the meaning would be easier, but when to see the detailed-portion of the image, people could click on it.

Comment: Use a small one as a thumbnail for a link to a bigger one

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2191/325443

Comment: I did not mean to give more KBs or Pixels. I just meant adjusting the preview size. Obviously the users should properly crop, and avoid unnecessary details; but I meant, when there is a real need to post a bigger-sized image, like this-one: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/243414/what-is-the-function-of-picture-tube-charger ; there comes need to adjust the appearent-size (cm or inch on display-screen).   (PS. In this-image, I did-not cropped some porttion at the margin, as they act as evidence of photograph taken from a printed book)

Answer (score 2):

You might do it in markdown like this:

```
[![][2]][1]

  [1]: http://about.keysight.com/en/newsroom/imagelibrary/library/seminarAplus_images/image003_high.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrDAP.jpg
```

With the following result:

[image]

You can also use the "add image" button in the editor, and just change the link target afterwards.

Comment: This image is a perfect example of why this features isn't needed in the first place.  Start with the high-res version of this image, crop off all the fluff past the scope trace, then filter that down to 640 pixels wide.  The result will convey everything you need it too, AND be less annoying to look at due to less clutter.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: sure, I was just too lazy to find an image where it might matter. There is indeed not much cases where proper cropping doesn't do the business. I somewhat wish we had the ability to crop while uploading/editing, instead of having to do it externally, that would help a lot.

Comment: That's exactly my point.  It's hard to find a genuine case where this would be useful.  I can actually think of one on EE.SE, but many more with no cropping and bad composition.  Think of the many cases where we've had full-res out of focus cell phone images of a small connector in the middle of large picture dumped on us.  Giving people this tool will encourage far more crap than the rare case it is actually used appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

You get 640 pixels across already.  That's actually a lot if used properly.

A better answer is therefore to properly trim and otherwise edit or compose the image.  Of course this should be done anyway.  All too often we see sloppily designed images dumped on us.  These include schematics with lots of unnecessary white space, way too thin lines, etc.

A properly designed 640 pixel wide image can convey a lot of information.  If you need more than that, then step back and re-think what information is truly relevant.  Wanting to show a large image is highly correlated with poor presentation, not thinking about the question clearly, rambling, and just plain laziness.

Let's not give lazy people yet another tool to write bad questions.

Comment: I didn't meant to give more pixels or KBs. The supported image-size is more-than-enough for me. I meant; could I adjust the preview or display-size inside the text, (including adjusting image-position etc.)

Comment: By the way, I trim the white-spaces in my image as much I can ... to reduce internet cost.